# How to find the namespace defined by self when building a static library with XCode

Tags: c++, ios, xcode

I got a C++ project(totally in C++) from my colleague and need to build a static library with Xcode. In his code, a namespace called config was defined in config.hh and config.cc. But when I started to build the library, in another file using config.cc, the parser shows the error "Expected namespace name". How to solve this problem. The include code is below:

```
#include "lib/config.hh"
using namespace config;
```

Answer (score 1):

Command + click `config` on the line `using namespace config;` to see where Xcode thinks it is defined. What I can imagine is that there is a preprocessor macro line somewhere that over-defines config, i.e. `#define config`.

Once you find where the overridden definition is, you have some options:

- You can rename the `namespace` to something else
- You can remove / rename the other definition

Comment: I am sure that it link to the implement file of config.hh and there isn't any re-defined code :)

Comment: @Ellise I've checked, and it looks like LLVM will produce the same (a bit misleading) error message if it does not find the namespace that you are referencing. Can you maybe show how the namespace is declared in config.hh?